# rails set selection value to null rather than blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code which allows a user to select a currency rather than inheriting one.

```
%dd= user_field(@user, :remuneration_currency, :type => :select, :collection => REMUNERATION_CURRENCIES)
```

I need to allow people to set this field back to NULL, which means that the user will pick up their account's default currency. However, if I change the code to this...

```
%dd= user_field(@user, :remuneration_currency, :type => :select, :collection => REMUNERATION_CURRENCIES, :blank => 'Company Default')
```

then it sets the value to blank (as it says on the tin) rather than NULL in the database. How do I set the 'Company Default' value to be NULL rather than blank.

Comment: Gareth, have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to use the gem [nilify_blanks](https://github.com/rubiety/nilify_blanks) which does exactly what you are looking for:

> In Rails when saving a model from a form and values are not provided
>   by the user, an empty string is recorded to the database instead of a
>   NULL as many would prefer (mixing blanks and NULLs can become
>   confusing). This plugin allows you to specify a list of attributes (or
>   exceptions from all the attributes) that will be converted to nil if
>   they are blank before a model is saved.